# No such element: Unable to locate element - selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to toggle to different menu items and download some reports on Amazon Vendor Central. Attached is an image of the script of one of the dropdown items[image: ![enter image description here]

Here, I am interested in selecting the "Shipped COGS" option instead of "Shipped Revenue" option that is currently selected.

[image]

I tried the following code [Updated based on inputs from cruisepandey]:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import re
import time

driver.get("https://vendorcentral.amazon.de/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
# enter the email
email = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']")))
email.send_keys("***")

# enter password
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("***")

driver.get("https://vendorcentral.amazon.de/analytics/dashboard/salesDiagnostic")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Shipped COGS']"))).click()
```

I was getting the "element not found" error earlier. Now, it is coming up with a TimeoutException. Kindly advise how to proceed. Thanks!

UPDATE::

The following code works now:

```
# To click on the dropdown object
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='dashboard-filter-viewFilter']"))).click()

# To select the list item within the dropdown object
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='dashboard-filter-viewFilter']/div/awsui-button-dropdown/div/div/ul/li[3]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this xpath :

```
//select[@id='dashboard-filter-viewFilter']
```

here `select` is basically a `tag`, and `id` is an `attribute` and `dashboard-filter-viewFilter` is `attribute value`.

But I do not see any `select tag` in the `screenshot` that you've shared.

Instead, it is `a span tag` not `select`.

**Fix :**

```
//span[@id='dashboard-filter-viewFilter']
```

Also, make sure the following

1. This span is not under an iframe.
2. This span is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

Also, check-in `HTMLDOM` that if we have unique entry or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Also, the code that you've

```
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='dashboard-filter-viewFilter']"))
```

would not work for drop-down built using div and span tag, they will work only in case of select and option tag.

I would suggest that you try to click on drop down bar first and the once options are visible try to click on one of the desired option.

This question does not have sufficient amount of HTML to give you the second solution.

Comment: But the question was: _interested in selecting the "Shipped COGS" option instead of "Shipped Revenue"_ How does this answer helps?

Comment: @DebanjanB : I don't see any select tag in `HTMLDOM`, moreover he is getting `No such element: Unable to locate element ` . This should address your _How does this answer helps?_

Comment: @SVK KVS : If in HTMLDOM you see select tag, you will have to share that with us here in text format. Also the code that you've `Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='dashboard-filter-viewFilter']"))` would not work for drop down built using div and span tag, they will work only in case of select and option tag.

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey and @DebanjanB! I have updated the image now to include the full path of getting to the element. I tried searching for the element using the Find on Chrome and it picks the correct element.  Changing from Select to Span also helped locate the element in the code. 

Now, Shipped Revenue is the option that is currently chosen, but I would like to choose another item in the dropdown list - namely Shipped COGS. How should I go about doing that? Thanks again very much!!!

Comment: @SVKKVS  : Still I do not see `Shipped COGS` in HTML. When you open that HTML do you see that option populating ?

Comment: Yes, Shipped COGS appears in the HTML when that option is clicked from the drop down menu. I have added in another screenshot now. Thanks!

Comment: @SVKKVS : Are you able to click on drop down bar ?

Comment: @cruisepandey: Yes, I am able to click on that option from the drop down list.

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Shipped COGS']"))).click()` please use this code to click on COGS

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`  - You would need to import these as well.

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey! I tried the above and am getting a TimeoutException. I have imported the said libraries as well.

Comment: Can you updated your question with the newly code that you've tried ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238980/discussion-between-svk-kvs-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: I know this will also throw an error
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[text()='Shipped COGS']").click()`
but this should lead us in right direction